Можно ли как-то заставить Visual Studio парсить в выводе внешнего компилятора error/warning для перехода к строчке кода с ошибкой?
Для работы с Makefile-проектом на C решил использовать Visual Studio. Всё устраивает, Intellisense работает: код дополняет, ошибки показывает. Но есть небольшая проблема - т.к. используется сторонний компилятор RVCT, вывод у него отличается от того, что ждёт VS, т.е. , например, приходит такое сообщение об ошибке в окно Output:

src/fota/fota.c", line 93 : error : #20: identifier "s" is undefined"

В окне ошибок данная ошибка будет видна:

#20: identifier "s" is undefined

Но никак нельзя перейти к строке кода, в которой эта ошибка есть. Ни из окна Output, ни из окна Error List.
Есть ли возможность настроить студию, чтобы можно было настроить навигацию по ошибкам/предупреждениям?
Использую Visual Studio 2017

Можно пропустить вывод через какую-нибудь программу, которая перевела бы его в привычный для студии формат (я бы сделал на awk, делайте на чем привычнее). Можно заменить VS на VSC, там можно регулярками парсить произвольный формат. Но вообще, часто ли нужно смотреть в ошибки компилятора, если интелисенс и так все показывает?
